# Should I validate response data in jQuery's ajax success handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Let's assume I have a post AJAX call and I want to put returned data into some HTML elements.

```
$.post(settings.url, function(data) {
    $('#someElement').text(data.someData1);
    $('#someElement2').text(data.someData2);
});
```

I'm a back-end developer and it's natural for me that I have to do server-side validation of any piece of data coming from user. Although it's the opposite situation, the code above feels a little bit wrong for me (not validated *outside* data). But on the other hand, I know what I'm returning from the server.

The question is if is it *fine* to trust that `data` returned from (also mine)  back-end application will have expected structure, or should I validate somehow every data coming server?

Additional question is if there is some nice method to do such validation? Manual validating of existence of every piece of data seems to be a pain in the neck. Especially for more complex data structure.

Just during writing this question an idea came to my mind. I could use `$.extend()` just like it's commonly used for setting default options while writing modules/plugins. Something like:

```
$.post(settings.url, function(data) {
    var trustedStructure = $.extend({
        someData1:  $('#someElement').text(),
        someData2:  $('#someElement2').text(),
    }, data);

    $('#someElement').text(trustedStructure .someData1);
    $('#someElement2').text(trustedStructure .someData2);
});
```

That way I could have trusted data with additionally current data as default or any other if I want.

**Edit:**
Forgot to note. I'm talking about pure JSON data responses. No HTML etc included.

Comment: @Andreas yes, of course. It's just a code that I wrote without testing to show my idea and this part was ctrl+c/v from earlier one ;-).

Comment: If you don't trust it, absolutely.

Comment: @KevinB I don't trust future myself ;-) And also I'd like to know what the common approach.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you don't validate the response data, as you said before, the data is returned from your own back-end. What you really need to do is to ensure that you have a proper way to handle exceptions or errors with the information coming from the server.

If you're returning an exception from the server you should have a way in the client-side to figure out that if an error or not.

i.e. returning a specific code like a [Rest API](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) or having a JSON structure like this:

```
// Success
{
    "error": false,
    "data": {
       ...
    }
}
// Exception
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Username already taken",
    "type": "warning"
}
```

If you always return a **200 OK** status code:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error.message);
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#field').value = response.data.text;
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML Response Codes are useful when you use [promises](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html), you can return a **200 OK** for the primary flow (success, done), and **4XX** or **5XX** if something unusual happen (fail):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    ...
})
.done(function(response) { alert(response.data); })    
.fail(function(error) { alert(error.message); })    
.always(function() { clearFields(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the data returned from your server contain DOM Elements?

If it doesn't and is a pure text return, you can use a `textarea` to parse incoming data like this:

```
var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
textArea.innerHTML = data;
data = textArea.textContent;
```

Just try it out and let the server send some `<p>`, `<img>` or `<script>` Elements

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Response I meant is JSON object. A want particular properties put into particular existing DOM elements. Anyway that's just an example and I may need to do some logic on returned data in the future too.

Comment: You can of course use that method for those single properties before inserting them into the DOM

Comment: Yes, but I'm kind of asking about validation JSON object structure itself. You know, to check if particular property exists. And it's more about tactic in JS in general than solving a particular issue.

Comment: Ah, okay, I get it now. But it doesn't seem to me like you are risking a security problem when not checking for every single JSON field being present or not. Usually I expect the incoming data to be fine and do additional checking where it's necessary (like when inserting stuff from an AJAX call into the DOM)

Comment: Exactly, that's what my brain tells me. ;-) But on the other hand it's often worth to protect your code from yourself. :) In case making it easier to debug it later when you break something making changes (e.g. on server side).

Comment: That sounds more like a scenario for automated testing of your API. The frontend shouldn't be responsible for telling you when you had a breaking change in your API, an automated test should do that